# WebSecurity ignoring does not working with AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I created a filter and in the filter super constructor it requires a `defaultFilterProcessesUrl`. I selected all requests by url `/v1/**`.

I need to go not logged in `/v1/users` (`POST` method) and `/v1/users/signin` (`POST` method), but the filter does not allow. How to solve this problem?

JWT filter:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter() {
        super("/v1/**");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

         String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
         if(header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer")){
             throw new RuntimeException("JWT token is missing");
         }

         String authenticationToken = header.substring(7);

        JwtAuthenticationToken token = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authenticationToken);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Spring Security configuration:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(){
        return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(authenticationProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter(){
        JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JwtSuccessHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v1/users")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v1/users/signin")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/token");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
             .csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("SG_ADMIN", "O_ADMIN", "OS_ADMIN")
                .and()
             .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and()
             .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the other constructor with a [`RequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html), see [`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter-org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher-):

> **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter**
>
> `protected AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter(RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher)`
>
> Creates a new instance
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher` - the `RequestMatcher` used to determine if authentication is required. Cannot be null.

Your modified code:

```
public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter() {
    super(customRequestMatcher);
}
```

with

```
 RequestMatcher customRequestMatcher = new AndRequestMatcher(
      new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/**"), 
      new NegatedRequestMatcher(
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/users", "POST")
      ),
      new NegatedRequestMatcher(
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/users/signin", "POST")
      )
 );
```